# Recover ZFS data

Tags: linux, zfs, disaster-recovery

Context/Hardware:

- HP microserver gen8
- 1x1TB - standalone, 2x4TB Raid
- 1x16GB iLO SDCARD with Debian + OpenMediaVault

Event:

- SDCARD failure
- restarted server and installed Ubuntu on 1TB drive

Consequences:

- ZFS not accessible anymore

  ```
  root@fremen:~# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
  NAME   FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL     
  sda    zfs_member 931,5G                               
  └─sda1 ext4       931,5G /                             
  sdb    zfs_member   3,7T                               
  └─sdb1 zfs_member   3,7T                              
  sdc    zfs_member   3,7T                               
  └─sdc1 zfs_member   3,7T                               
  sdd                 5,7G

  root@fremen:~# zpool import -D -f 
  no pools available to import

  root@fremen:~# file -s /dev/sd?1
  /dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=9c46f52c-b529-4c39-a23b-819726f79146 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
  /dev/sdb1: data
  /dev/sdc1: data
  ```
- Disks seem to be still on the ZFS pool but no data is accessible.

What to do in this situation? It is a friend's setup and I can connect remotely to the machine. I do not want to create a new pool as it will destroy data on ZFS volumes. As I cannot find pools on disks zdb cannot be used.

Comment: Don't use `-D` with `zpool import`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Even without '-D' there is no available pool.

Comment: That's really odd. Was there actually a zpool there? Did someone erase it? You might need to restore from backup.

Comment: Indeed, it is odd. The only idea that I have right now is that the pool info was written on the iLO sdcard and now cannot be accessed. I'm wondering how to dig deeper for data. Unfortunately I couldn't find any tool able to do low level disk inspection (a la testdisk) so that I can recover some of his files.

Comment: Please post the output of `file -s /dev/sd?1`

Answer (score 3):

Michael Hampton comments were the solution for this.

It turns out that OMV in fact didn't use ZFS at all but just marked the drives as ZFS members.

I have dd-ed one of the drives and on the image I ran testdisk. It turned out that there was a 0x0700 partition on the disk. Wrote a new partition table with testdisk and mounted it in loop. It turned out to be an ext4 partition with corrupted journal. After fixing the errors I was able to salvage all the data.
Hence I did the same on the physical disks, got the data back.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the method of using dd first and working with the image. That's really something I'll remember forever.